# How to cycle through a list with an offset?

Tags: clojure

What is the best way / easiest way to cycle through a list with an offset?

Here's a possible solution

```clj
(defn getNoteVals [notes offset]
  (for [n (range (count notes))]
    (nth notes (mod (+ offset n) (count notes)))))
```

Comment: This takes time proportional to the *square* of the length of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more idiomatic way

```clj
(defn offset-list [a-list offset]
  (->> (cycle a-list)
       (drop offset)
       (take (count a-list))))
```

---

[cycle doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cycle)

> Returns a lazy (infinite!) sequence of repetitions of the items in
>   coll.

E.g.

```clj
user=> (take 5 (cycle ["a" "b"]))
("a" "b" "a" "b" "a")
```

Comment: Interesting. Are they lazy even on n+1st cycle or only on the first? (or is this an ill-posed question)

Answer (score 3):

you can also employ `split-at` for that:

```
(defn process [offset data] 
  (let [[l r] (split-at offset data)] 
    (concat r l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cycle`:

```
(defn getNoteVals [notes offset]
  (take (count notes) (drop offset (cycle notes))))
```

this is potentially slow if `offset` is large so you could also do:

```
(defn get-note-values [notes offset]
  (let [n (count notes)
        d (rem offset n)]
    (concat (drop d notes) (take d notes))))
```